# How to perform a loop to evaluate a function with different values of x in R?

Tags: r, function, loops

I created a function and I want to evaluate that function at different values of x. I did a loop for this and I expected the result to be a vector with the different values of the function. However, something I am doing wrong, because of the two ways I tried to do this I did not get the expected vector.

```
my_function <- function(x) x^2

#First try
for(i in seq(0.1, 1, 0.1)) {
  y[i] <- my_function(i)
}
y

#Second try
for(i in seq(0.1, 1, 0.1)) {
  y[i] <- my_function[i]
}
y
```

The first attempt resulted in:

```
> y
[1] 1
```

The second attempt resulted in:

```
object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

I would like to obtain a resulting vector, composed of the function values evaluated at 0.1, 0.2, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second attempt, it is trying to extract a value with an index and the `myfunction` is a function.  So, it should be `(i)`

Instead, what we need is a vector to store the values

```
x <- seq(0.1, 1, 0.1)
y <- numeric(length(x))
```

Or else y gets updated in each iteration and the value we get is from the last iteration

```
for(i in seq_along(x)) {
   y[i] <- my_function(x[i])
 }
```

---

Note that `my_function` is a vectorized one.  So, we don't need any loop

```
my_function(x)
```